# How to make sure my DataFrame frees its memory?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, garbage-collection, apache-spark-sql

I have a Spark/Scala job in which I do this:

- 1: Compute a big DataFrame `df1` + `cache` it into memory
- 2: Use `df1` to compute `dfA`
- 3: Read raw data into `df2` (again, its big) + `cache` it

When performing (3), I do no longer need `df1`. I want to make sure its space gets freed. I `cached` at (1) because this DataFrame gets used in (2) and its the only way to make sure I do not recompute it each time but only once.

I need to free its space and make sure it gets freed. What are my options?

I thought of these, but it doesn't seem to be sufficient:

- `df=null`
- `df.unpersist()`

Can you document your answer with a proper Spark documentation link?

Comment: Might be an instance of the [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - why would you have to force GC? What are you trying to solve with that?

Comment: When computing, my memory gets pretty much full and I want to free some space used by a DataFrame I don't need anymore (I cached it to ease up some redundant computations, but I don't want it anymore).

Comment: I edited to avoid falling into the XY problem.

Comment: @belka are you running out of cache space or non-cache space?  If it's not cache space that's running out, clearing the cache wont help.

Comment: @puhlen I'm running out of cache space (RAM memory).

Comment: @belka there are multiple parts to ram memory, one of them is cache, another is regular execution heap space.  When cache space runs out, the program wont crash, just some partitions won't be cached and be reevaluated when needed.  When execution heap runs out you may get an out-of-memory error.  If you are running out of regular heap memory, freeing up cache space wont help

Comment: @puhlen No no don't worry, it's not an heap error ;)
I really want to keep all my next DataFrame in cache, make sure it has enough space so that I avoid recomputing parts of my data later.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`df.unpersist` should be sufficient, but it won't necessarily free it right away.  It merely marks the dataframe for removal.

You can use `df.unpersist(blocking = true)` which will block until the dataframe is removed before continuing on.

Comment: Will this block the dataframe aside or the execution timeline?

Comment: @belka it blocks execution (as in the thread will stop and wait for the dataframe to be uncached)

Comment: As far as my experience goes, this blocks the execution of all machines before resuming in this case.

Answer (score 5):

User of Spark has no way to manually trigger garbage collection.

Assigning `df=null` is not going to release much memory, because DataFrame does not hold data - it is just a description of computation.

If your application has memory issue have a look at [Garbage Collection tuning guide](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/docs/tuning.md#garbage-collection-tuning). It has suggestion where to start and what can be changed to improve GC

Comment: Actually, you do have a way to make sure your object will be garbage collected: you set your variable (object reference) to `null` and at the next round of chekups, IF your object has no longer any other pointer referencing it, it should be garbage collected.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Assume I cached my DataFrame, hence it does not contain a description of future computations to be done but the data, isn't it? + What does `unpersist` do in this case?

Answer (score 1):

df.unpersist(blocking = true) This will solve the issue

For further explanation -> https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/spark-dataframe-cache-and-persist-explained/