# Why doesnt spark unload memory even with unpersist

Tags: loops, apache-spark, memory, pyspark, amazon-emr

I have spark job that has a nested for loop. The reason I use a nested for loop is that I have a very large dataset that is paritioned into `modules` and I dont want to load all the partitions into memory to do my work. I have `8` modules and the pseudocode is something like this:

```
inpath="s3://path"
modules=fs.ls(inpath)

for path in modules:
    modulepath='s3://' +path+ '/'
    module=path.split('=')[1]
    df=spark.read.option("basePath",inpath).parquet(modulepath)
    df=df.persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK)
    inter_df=[]

    iter=[1,2,3]    
    for i in iter:
        #perform calculations that involve slicing and dicing df for 3 iterations
        df2=slice_n_dice(df)
        df2=df2.persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK)

        df3=cut_n_whip(df)
        df3=df3.persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK)

        df4=mix_n_mash(df2,df3)
        inter_df.append(df4)

    final_df=reduce(DataFrame.unionByName, inter_df)
    fina_df=final_df.persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK)
    final_df=fina_df.withColumn() #Adding a bunch of calculated columns to final_df

    final_df.write.parquet("s3//filename_" +module +".parquet")

    final_df.unpersist()
    df3.unpersist()
    df2.unpersist()
```

The reason I have many `persists` is that my data is large and when analyzing the DAG I find that it recomputes a lot and ends up with lost nodes. By utilizing `persist()` I was able to make it work.

However, when I run the job and look at the CPU load and memory, I dont see the memory being cleared out after each outer loop even though I used `unpersist()`

[image]
[image]

As can be seen in the above CPU load in Ganglia, the 8 loops take place as expected. However, in the memory graph, I don't see any unpersisting occurring after each outer loop. The cache simply keeps on increasing until it seems to finish the job.

Am I doing understanding it wrong or using `unpersist` in a wrong way?
Any pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Thank You

Comment: I think you should persist Dataframe 'df' instead of df2 and df3 because you are not using df2 and df3 multiple times as per code snippet unless you have some logic in the pseudo functions internally. Also I don't understand why you would have to do 3 iterations on a specific partition and what is the benefit that you are getting out of it as it would scan the entire partition and there might not be any benefit that you might be getting.

Comment: Actually, I do persist `df` also. Sorry, I forgot to add it in the pseudocode. 
And i need to do the 3 iterations in the inner loop because I am sampling 3 different time windows within each module partition. My dataset is partitioned by `module` and `date`

Answer (score 2):

You can refer to this post [How to make sure my DataFrame frees its memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49074070/how-to-make-sure-my-dataframe-frees-its-memory)

and spark documentation http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html#removing-data

[image]

what I understand is that unpersist only marks the dataframe for removal but it won't be dropped from memory immediately unless you use (blocking=true) and wait for the removal to complete.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work when I try `df.unpersist(True)` . In fact the job failes and keeps re-trying.