# How to delete RDD with unpersist

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, memory, rdd

I'm trying to understand how `RDD.unpersist()` works but I'm running into some confusing output.

When I force-delete an RDD and then try to show it:

```
rdd.unpersist(blocking=True)
rdd.show() # why doesn't this line throw an error?
```

I expect the second line to error, but it doesn't. The RDD prints out as usual.

I saw these two questions: [Why doesnt spark unload memory even with unpersist](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68615037/10753968), [How to make sure my DataFrame frees its memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49074070/10753968). They were both helpful in understanding how to use `unpersist` but don't answer my question.

I'm using a Jupyter notebook and wondered if the notebook might be caching the RDD, so I tested this out in a .py file as well, and the same thing happened.

**If the RDD has been deleted, why does it print when `show()` is called on it?**

**If it hasn't been deleted, how can I delete it?**

Comment: Why do you expect `rdd.show()` to throw an error? The RDD is still there (i.e., the DAG/plan/transformation sequence is what the `RDD` is) and the `.show()` action will cause things to run again from the source through to the last transformation. What would be weird is if the loaded data isn't removed after `.unpersist(True)`. And those are 2 distinct things.

Comment: You're saying that calling `show()` causes the RDD to be recreated? If yes, what's a better way to check that the RDD has been deleted?

Comment: I mean calling `rdd.show()` must reload the data. The `rdd` object itself contains the plan needed to do that. You should distinguish between "data has been removed" and "RDD has been deleted". The latter doesn't make sense.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for explaining. If you add your explanation as an answer I'll accept it

Comment: Calling `rdd.select()` and `rdd.take()` also reload the data, it seems - is there a way to see that the data was removed? (eg see that count=0 or there are no rows to print)

Comment: @half of a glazier `rdd.unpersist(blocking=True)` doesn't really work, that is because this RDD never cached in memory. When `rdd.show()` is work, Spark will reload the data of this RDD from disk, so `rdd.show()` will not throw an error. `rdd.unpersist()` only remove the cache in memory.

Comment: Why are you using  RDD API in 2023rd? Is anything blocking you from using DataFrames?

Comment: @AlexOtt I'm learning Spark so started with RDDs because that's what most tutorials go into... I only realised after that DFs are the way to go now

Comment: Can you point to a specific tutorial? For Spark introduction you can get the "Learning Spark, 2nd edition" book - it was freely distributed by Databricks (not sure if it's still freely distributed)

Comment: I've been using DataQuest but they're not very comprehensive

Answer (score 1):

You can check the rdd is cached or not by using the attribute `is_cached`.

```
rdd = sc.parallelize([1, 2, 3])
print(rdd.is_cached)
rdd.cache()
print(rdd.is_cached)
rdd.unpersist()
print(rdd.is_cached)
rdd.count() -- ignore response
print(rdd.is_cached)

False
True
False
False
```

Without cache call, the rdd is not cached and unpersist is not working as you expected. It will not delete rdd itself, just remove cached version. How do you delete a variable?